# A segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I have try the following code to judge prime:

```
const int N = 200000;
long prime[N] = {0};
long num_prime = 0;
int is_not_prime[N]={1,1};
void Prime_sort(void)
{
    for( long i = 2 ; i<N ; i++ )
    {
        if( !is_not_prime[i] )
        {
            prime[num_prime++] = i;
        }
        for( long j = 0; j<num_prime && i*prime[i]<N ; j++ )
        {
            is_not_prime[i*prime[j]] = 1;
        }   
    }   
}
```

But when I run it, it cause a segmentation fault! **That fault I have never meet**.And I searched Google,and it explain segmentation fault as follow:

> A segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault) is a particular
>   error condition that can occur during the operation of computer
>   software. In short, a segmentation fault occurs when a program
>   attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access,
>   or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed

But I don't know where cause this fault in my code.Please help me.

Comment: Segmentation fault means your program has a bug causing it to write outside the memory where it should be writing. Array out of bounds bugs for example, will cause seg faults. It is one of the most common bugs in C.

Comment: @Lundin But in my code where will cause arry out of bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your loop bound checking to your indexing - they aren't the same. (I believe you meant to write `i*prime[j]<N` in your `for` loop.)

Answer (score 4):

Your array `is_not_prime` has length N. For example, at the final lap of the outer for loop, i will have the value `N-1`. When `i` is that big, `is_not_prime[i*prime[j]]` will cause you to write far out of bounds of the array.

I'm not quite sure what `j<num_prime && i*prime[i]<N` is supposed to do, but it is likely part of the bug. Single step through the program with your debugger and see at what values the variables have when the program crashes.

Just re-write your program in a less complex manner and all bugs will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Your program crashes because an index goes out of bounds. And the index goes out of bounds because your algorithm is not valid.

As it still crashes if you set N at a much smaller value

```
const int N = 3;
```

it shouln't be too difficult to see what goes wrong by running your program with pencil and paper...